# How to encrypt and decrypt data using sync framework?

Tags: synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I am working with C# win form application.
My application download sensitive data from server side and stored in client side.
Whenever there is no internet connection it stored data at local end. As soon as connection get, it upload data at remote end that is server side.
It download user credential and stored at local end(user table), because when no internet connection , more users can access this application without server validation(validation done at local end).

My question is, I stored user credential at local end. How i encrypt data at local end so no user can access or see other user's data using sync framework 2.1 ?

please suggest me any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sync Framework is for data synchronization. if you want do to something extra for your data, do it before you sync.

likewise, regardless of whether you use Sync Framework or not, you require it to be encrypted anyway right?

so the security of your data on the mobile is outside the concern of Sync Framework so you will have to secure it yourself.

Comment: yes, you are right but.if i do encryption before sync process. i need to temporary table and sync doesn't support temporary object.currently i have 18 tables so if i start encryption / decryption before sync i required 36 tables. after sync up i need to encrypt 18 tables and after copied it another 18 table.and  truncate 18 tables(which contain original synced data not encrypted format). am i right?. have you another solution, please help me..!